# Google Books search results and API results are different

Tags: google-api, google-books, google-books-api

I'm currently using Google Books API(https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using)

And It's weird that search results from the actual website or mobile app and search results from the API are different.

see my pic.

[this is mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBfD3.png)

[this is website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZefK.png)

and this is my query

[https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=r김란주&langRestrict=ko&maxResults=10&startIndex=0](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=r%EA%B9%80%EB%9E%80%EC%A3%BC&langRestrict=ko&maxResults=10&startIndex=0)

I searched korean word "김란주".

What have I missed?

I tried query parameters. (https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#api_params)

But I didn't get the same result as the app or site.

And I found same situation. ([The results of the Google books API and the website are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74144306/the-results-of-the-google-books-api-and-the-website-are-different))

please help me. thx.

Comment: Please post your code so we can look at it and provide further assistance.